# Hide cursor in Word

Tags: vba, winapi, ms-word, vsto, caret

Is there a programmatic or manual way of temporarily hiding the cursor (or caret, i.e. not the mouse pointer), either in VBA, VSTO or through Win API? I tried calling [HideCaret](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) API, but it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: maybe this can help, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/94318#/en-us/kb/94318, createCaret maybe a 0 height/width one, or a blank one.  Or look at LoadCursorFromFileA

Comment: *"doesn't appear to work"* is not an error description. What is the return value in case of failure? Did you verify, that the window for which you are calling [HideCaret](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648403.aspx) owns the caret? Did you respect the fact, that `HideCaret`/`ShowCaret` are cumulative?

Comment: @IInspectable: `HideCaret` returns `false`. And it can't be caused by the cumulative-ness because I never call `ShowCaret`; the very first `HideCaret` call fails. Also why would document's caret not be owned by document window? Is there a way to check that?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: Your comment has opened a new line of thinking for me. It may be that `HideCaret` works with TextBoxes only, while the Word document window is not a TextBox. Maybe that Word is using its own special mechanism for showing the caret, not the one provided by Windows. Could that be the case?

Comment: The Word document editor may not even use a standard caret. Since it doesn't look like a standard Edit or Rich Text control it is very likely that Word implements custom rendering (including the caret).

Comment: Certainly, neither VBA nor VSTO (that only extends the object model) provide a way to hide the Insertion Point (correct Office technical term for the blinking thingy on the document surface). Sometimes, when the focus in the application is elsewhere, it can disappear, but no 100% reproducible steps (especially via the object model) occur to me. Why would hiding it be important for you?

Comment: @CindyMeister: I'm working on an add-in, which invents its own way of handling where the next character will go. Word's Insert Point becomes very obstructive and misleading for the user in that situation.

Comment: One thing you can try is to set Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = False. If nothing else, it should stop the blinking. Something I've never tried but could work would be to open a non-modal form, but so small and/or off the window that the user doesn't notice it. If the focus is in that then the IP shouldn't be blinking. (Or even a modal form, which would keep the user from trying to work in the document at all until you're ready to allow it.)

Comment: you can put HideCaret in a loop while( not true), consequently check for GetLastError;

Comment: @milevyo: There is no caret, so your hack won't work. In this case it merely breaks code. A classic lose-lose situation.

Comment: @IInspectable, i maybe didn't understand the question. am i missing something?

Comment: @IInspectable, in case there is no caret `GetLastError` will return an error. is there other thing that we can try better than this.